# "Many people" vs. "much people" — which one should be used?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, determiners

> - There's so *many* people in here!
> - There's so *much* people here!

Which one should be used, and why?

Comment: "There wasn't much people about that day." — Bram Stoker, *Dracula*. "Sir Launcelot will abide
me and you in the Joyous Gard; and much people draweth
unto him, as I hear say." — Sir Thomas Malory, *Le Morte d'Arthur*. "But when Jesus was come down from the hill, much people followed him" — Matthew 8:1, *The Bible*. I'd say the case is settled.

Comment: Which one should be used? Depends on whether you're writing standard or doge.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you can count it and it doesn't designate a category, use *many*.

If you cannot count it or it designates a category, use *much*.

> I have many friends.
>   I have much to offer.
>   There are many ways to get it wrong.
>   It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: And to answer the question… the correct one is "many people".

Answer (score 7):

Many is used in enumerated quantities. If it can be counted in individual items, use *many*. If the quantity cannot be counted, use *much*.

"There are so *many* people in here!"

"There is so *much* I still need to learn!"

Comment: Much is also used for quantities by weight "How much flour do I need?" whereas "How many pounds of flour do I need?"

Answer (score 5):

Simple rule of thumb: if the following word is plural use many, otherwise much

> "I don't have much time"
>
> "I don't have many books"
>
> "how much money do you have?"
>
> "how many cars can you see?"