# “many modifies more” or “more modifies many”

Tags: expressions, differences

Sentence 1

> Many more people in poor areas have eye problems.

Sentence 2

> I have many more books than she does.

I have a feeling that

Sentence 1 
“**many more**” focuses on “**many**”, meaning **a lot of people have eye problems.**

Sentence 2 “**many more**” focuses on “**more**”, meaning **I have far more books than she does.**

In sentence 1 **more** modifies **many**, and in sentence 2 **many** modifies **more**.

Is that so?

Comment: "Many" modifies "more."  "More" modifies "people," or whatever the ensuing noun is.  It is not a matter of opinion.  It is a point of fact.  Your arbitrary feelings about what your examples focus on are just that: arbitrary.  They only actually do that if you yourself provide that emphasis.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I had another idea. Can I interpret the first “many more” as “more than many”? After reading your review, I started to doubt it. Do you mean in any context, “many more +noun” only means what it means in sentence 2. Besides, sentence 1 is from my English textbook.

Comment: The first sentence isn't a complete sentence. It's a comparative that's missing the thing being compared. If you want to say that a lot of people have eye problems, then say that. As it stands, it's not a complete thought.

Answer (score 0):

"Many more" does not mean "more than many" in either sentence. In both sentences, it is an emphasized form of "more". "Many more people in poor areas have eye problems" means "More people in poor areas have eye problems." You may be confused because this is an unusual use of the word *many*: [it is generally classified as an adverb in this construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/371353/77227), even though *many* is not usually used as an adverb.

Comment: It's because adverbs describe not just verbs but also adjectives.  Adjectives describe nouns.  Adverbs describe verbs and adjectives.  When "many" is used immediately before a noun, like "people," for example, it is an adjective, but when it's used before an adjective before a noun, like "many people," it is an adverb.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman: I'm not sure what you're responding to. *Many* is not usually used as an adverb either before a verb or before an adjective. I think the most common adverb used to emphasize the meaning of an adjective is *very*; comparative adjectives specifically are usually emphasized instead with the adverb *much* (as in *much better* or *much worse*). *Many* is used as an adverb only before the adjectives *more* and *fewer* (as far as I can tell). That is why I called this an unusual use of the word *many.*