# Can you say "much more people?"

Tags: british-english

Note this question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47918/many-more-vs-much-more-many-fewer-vs-much-fewer) because that question does not address the use of "far more".

It sounds strange to me but it's probably perfectly fine.  "Many more" or "far more people" sounds better.
The example sentence:

Much more people came to the party last time.

Answer (score 3):

*Can you say “much more people?”*

No - it is not grammatically correct or ever used. So either *Many more people came to the party last time.* or *Far more people came to the party last time.* Both are correct, and commonly used.

*Edited to add further to*:  *to explain a little more about when you would use "far more" and when you would use "many more". Are "many" and "far" both used interchangeably*. It is a question of degree mostly, with "far more" normally implying a much bigger increase than "many more" (in the context of countable items). I don't think there are any firm rules about it.

And in terms of adjectival use, both "far" and "much" are used: "I am far more comfortable ..." or "I am much more comfortable ...".

And also note that the opposite is *fewer* (used with countable items, like people or pencils) rather than *less* (used with indivisible quantities, such as water or paper). The more usual usage would be *far fewer* rather than *many fewer*.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you edit your answer to explain a little more about when you would use "far more" and when you would use "many more".  Are "many" and "far" both used interchangeably, for example when, as stated in [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6217/many-people-vs-much-people-which-one-should-be-used) "If you can count it and it doesn't designate a category, use many."?  Secondly, and only because you mentioned "fewer" and "less":  You use the "many"-"fewer" pair with countable and non category items and the "much"-"less" pair with non-countable or category items?